How to run `terraform test` on remote backend?
I have terraform tests running in CI/CD pipeline existing k8s cluster we have for testing. By default terraform tests using local state which is not saved anywhere in case of test cancelation. So I need time to time to cleanup temporary created resources manually.
Is there some way to run terraform test to save state somewhere remote for further possible manual terraform destroy execution?

Are you using a cloud provider? Which CI/CD tool are you using?

@MarkoE, I'm trying to configure it for Terraform Cloud workspace. CI/CD I have is "Azure DevOps" but it doesn't matter, because my local test execution also could be interrupted and created resources should be deleted even if local state file lost.
